# Swift: Conform Older Protocols to MainActor Isolation?

Tags: swift, actor, quicklook, swift-concurrency

## Context

I have a Mac app that uses the old QuickLook protocols: `QLPreviewPanelDataSource` and `QLPreviewPanelDelegate`. You select a row in an `NSTableView`, hit the spacebar, and you get the QuickLook preview. Standard stuff:

```
@MainActor
final class SomeController: NSTableViewDataSource, QLPreviewPanelDataSource
{
    private var tableView: NSTableView

    func numberOfPreviewItems(in panel: QLPreviewPanel!) -> Int {
       return tableView.numberOfSelectedRows
    }
}
```

## Problem

I'm adopting Actors and Swift Concurrency in this app. `SomeController` is now assigned to `@MainActor` as it should be, since it controls UI. But this brings warnings for the `-numberOfPreviewItems()` implementation:

```
Main actor-isolated instance method 'numberOfPreviewItems(in:)' cannot be used to satisfy nonisolated protocol requirement
```

`QLPreviewPanelDataSource` is not decorated with `@MainActor`, which would obviously solve the problem. I cannot simply mark the function `nonisolated`, since it touches `tableView`, which IS isolated to the Main Actor. And I cannot await an access, since the protocol method does not support concurrency.

Everything *works* fine, of course, but having 30-some spurious build warnings is a giant distraction.

## Question

What is the correct way to silence these warnings assuming:

1. Apple will **never** update the protocols with the `@MainActor` decoration. (Radars to do so are unanswered for years.)
2. I want to keep the `Strict Concurrency Checking` build setting set to `complete` to catch other, legitimate issues.

Comment: Are you looking only to silence the warnings, or are you willing to refactor the code to make it technically more compliant with the required behavior? For instance, you could pull out the `QLPreviewPanelDataSource` conformance into a dedicated data-source type that isn't actor isolated, and set properties on it from within `SomeController` (e.g., on selection, assign `tableView.numberOfSelectedRows` as a property on the data source so it doesn't need to touch `tableView`; etc.).

Comment: I wouldn’t be so sure about your first assumption, but let’s set that aside. Have you tried the `@preconcurrency` macro? That’s what it’s for, namely frameworks not yet updated for `Sendable`. See WWDC 2022 [Eliminate data races using Swift Concurrency](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/110351/?time=1550): “you can temporarily disable the Sendable warnings for types that come from that module using the @preconcurrency attribute.”

Comment: @rob Yes. I tried `@preconcurrency` on the `import quartz` line. Xcode tells me it’s unused and the warnings continue.

Comment: @ItaiFerber - That approach is doable, but it’s a lot of work/overhead and code bloat. There are *LOTS* of places in this app that support QuickLook, so wrapping them all would be tedious.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like `@preconcurrency` silences `Sendable` warnings, but not this actor isolation issue. I also tried putting this `QLPreviewPanelDataSource` conformance in an extension in its own file and tried overriding the `strict-concurrency` build setting in the build phases, but even that didn’t seem to work. Interesting question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you’ve pointed out, Apple has not isolated some legacy Objective-C classes, and given the requests have been open a while, it doesn’t seem like they will. Given this, it doesn’t seem possible to isolate an entire object without access to the object or protocol definition.

To address this isolation issue, Apple has provided [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/mainactor/assumeisolated(_:file:line:)-swift.type.method). I found this after running across this question when I had a similar issue

```swift
MainActor.assumeIsolated {}
```

I was building an ARKit feature and needed to conform to `ARSCNViewDelegate`, which is locked to the main thread in Objective-C, but considered `nonisolated` when it came to `Concurrency`. Since the delegate method returns a value, I couldn't wrap the body in a `Task`.

This is what worked for me:

```swift
@MainActor
class MyViewController: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate 
{
    // MARK: ARSCNViewDelegate methods

    nonisolated func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {
        return MainActor.assumeIsolated {
            // Assumed to be isolated to MainActor
            let node = SCNNode() // This line refuses to compile if not isolated since `SCNNode` is isolated to the MainActor.
            // Configure node and return.
            return node
        }
    }
}
```

No warnings, no errors.

Comment: I think, this is a valid workaround for the described issue. Not sure, why it has been downvoted. If this workaround is not possible in other scenarios, a technical correct solution would be to attempt to transform the values returned from the nonisolated delegate function to sendable values – still on the caller provided thread – and then using MainActor or a Task to switch to the main thread, passing the sendable values to the main actor isolated target. Note, that the latter cannot be used with delegates returning values.

Comment: This is what I tried at first, but (as you said) since this delegate method returns a value the scope couldn't stay structured/isolated. Thus the need to "assume" that it isolated (cause it's locked in objective c to "main"!) Thanks CouchDeveloper <3

Comment: Looks interesting! I'm not keen to pay a runtime penalty just to snuff out some annoying IDE warnings, though. In your case, you *had* to use this API to compile. In mine, I'm just flooded with spurious warnings.

Comment: @Bryan , you can also silence warnings in your code with the suggest solution from Brianna Doubt. I added an answer, but credit goes to Brianna.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper - thanks, but that still doesn't avoid the runtime overhead.

Comment: @Bryan - You didn’t mention any runtime overhead until these comments on an answer that works. This answer gives a first-party solution that yields no warnings with strict concurrency. What else do you want? Hahaha

Comment: @BriannaDoubt - Yea, I don't have a better solution and I'm tired of seeing 47 stupid build warnings, so the hacky workaround will have to suffice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As Brianna Doubt already figured out in her answer (do not credit me!), one can use [`MainActor\assumeIsolated(_:file:line:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/mainactor/assumeisolated(_:file:line:)-swift.type.method) to silence the the compiler warnings:

In your main actor isolated class, define the delegate function as follows:

```
    nonisolated
    func numberOfPreviewItems(in panel: QLPreviewPanel!) -> Int {
        assert(Thread.isMainThread)
        MainActor.assumeIsolated {
            return tableView.numberOfSelectedRows
        }
    }
```

The code above makes the assumption, that the delegate is called on the main thread. Since we cannot control the caller of the delegate, we cannot guarantee that this is actually the case. But at least, we can test it.

The `assert(Thread.isMainThread)` will catch any violation of our assumption in Debug configuration. However, `assumeIsolated(...)` will crash anyway if the code will not run on the main thread. So, the explicit assert is more for documentation making it double clear what we assume.

Then, `MainActor.assumeIsolated(..)` will silence the warnings.

Consider this as a workaround. Actually, Apple should address this issue and make it conform the concurrency rules.

**Side notes:**

You possibly do not need to make the whole class `MyViewController` isolated to the main actor. Possibly, there are other workarounds in your code.

Regarding your statement: "Apple will never update the protocols with the @MainActor decoration":

Possibly, they can't due to breaking APIs.

The other reason could be, that Apple don't *want* to isolate the delegate to the main actor, which makes sense for "data oriented" APIs. Either way, we don't know.